# Non existence of shape derivative of the eigenvalue of Dirichlet Laplacian

Tags: geometry, eigenfunctions

I am searching for the regularity of the domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ when the first shape derivative of the eigenvalue of Dirichlet Laplacian does not exist

Thank you for  any suggestions or references.

Comment: You ask for references. But it's us that need references from you... Very few people, I think, know what a shape derivative is ...

Comment: thank you @JeanMarie  for your interest, the definition is quite longer you can see this in the book : extremum problems for eigenvalues of elliptic operators